# v-model и объекты

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет.
Помогите разобраться с одним вопросом.

У меня на вью есть компонент, собирающий информацию о человеке в JSON
В этом компоненте есть плашка с "вос вопрсосами".
Вопросов может быть несколько
Соответвенно в JSON эти вопросы должны выглядеть вот так:

```
"Question":"[{первый вопрос и параметры},{второй вопрос и параметры},{...},]"
```

Вопрос...
Как на на вью собрать все эти данные в один массив ?

Сделать массив вопросов.
По завершению работы с карточкой копировать данные из переменных v-model связянных с полями ввода в один объект (только у карточки нет кнопки или какого-то события, которое говорило бы о завершении), который будет лежать в массиве, а потом отчищать эти поля для новой карточки? Или может есть какой способ получше ?
Нужно также сохранить доступ к этим данным в ходе заполнения карточки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сбора всех вопросов и их параметров в один массив можно

1. Создать массив для хранения вопросов

```js
const questions = [];
```

2. При каждом добавлении нового вопроса в плашку вопросов, создавать объект с параметрами и добавлять его в массив вопросов

```js
questions.push({
  question: 'Текст вопроса',
  answer: 'Ответ на вопрос',
  // Другие параметры вопроса
});
```

3. После заполнения всех вопросов и создания объектов с их параметрами, собрать все объекты в один JSON-объект

```js
const data = {
  questions: questions
};
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Теперь в переменной jsonData будет находиться JSON-объект, содержащий массив с вопросами и их параметрами.

Чтобы сохранить доступ к данным в ходе заполнения карточки, можно использовать массив `questions`, который хранит объекты с параметрами вопросов. В этом массиве будут находиться все введенные пользователем данные, которые можно использовать для обработки или вывода на страницу. После завершения работы с карточкой можно очистить поля ввода и очистить массив questions для создания новой карточки.

Comment: В jsonData не будет объекта